# pfSense - expose LAN to the WAN network

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, pfsense

I am at the point I really need some help to configure pfSense. I am getting no support from the IT and half of the time I am not sure things are not working because of me and my limited experience, or because the IT is not allowing them.

I have a server running ESXi 7. The server is connected to a switch (managed by the IT), via two NICs, however the IT is allowing me to have only one IP address, bound to one of the two NICs. In ESXi I have two VMs, which I would need to be able to communicate to each other, communicate to the other servers connected to the same switch, and be reachable from my office pc (also in the same network).

I have successfully installed pfSense on ESXi after creating a WAN and a LAN virtual switch (each using a different uplink, using for WAN the NIC the IT-assigned IP is bound to), and a WAN and LAN port groups. pfSense is up and running, I can ping google.com or our dns server (not 8.8.8.8 tho, not sure why).

```
WAN (wan)       -> vmx1     -> v4/DHCP4: 172.21.251.104/24
LAN (lan)       -> vmx0     -> v4: 10.100.100.1/24
```

To both VMs I have the LAN connected, each VM can ping pfSense or the other VM. I have internet connection inside the VMs, but can only search things on google, cannot open any of the search result page. Also, I cannot access any of the other resources (servers, shares, ...) in the WAN network, or access the VM from my office PC.

What do I need to do in order to "expose" the LAN network to the WAN? A step-by-step instruction would be great, I have very limited knowledge about networking, I do other things for a living.

Comment: So you're not part of your organisation's IT department? Are you responsible for creating, deploying or adhering to your organisation's network designs and/or security designs?

Comment: Yes, I am not part of the IT dept. I can only request my machines to join the network (and I can have them joining the domain by myself), but I have no control on the switches.

Comment: I fear you'll get no help here sorry, the reason being that your IT department will have some company-mandated security policies which it's their job to police. You're asking for help in circumventing them. It'd be a bit like walking into a pilot's lounge at an airport asking for help to steal a plane :)